# cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization attempt to call method 'value'

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I am using the following code for slider

**Css and Jquery:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**ASPX:**

```
<p>
   <label for="amount">Value:</label> 
   <input type="text" id="amount" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />%
</p> 
<div id="slider-vertical" style="height: 15px; width:800px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#slider-vertical").slider({
            orientation: "horizantal", range: "min", min: 0, max: 100, value: 60,
            slide: function (event, ui)
            { $("#amount").val(ui.value); }
        });
        $("#amount").val($("#slider-vertical").slider("value"));
    });
</script>
```

I am trying to set the value for slider:

```
function UpdateSlider(PhaseInStatusReportVal) {
    $("#slider-vertical").slider("value").val(PhaseInStatusReportVal);
}
```

I am calling above code from something like this :

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "updatetheslider", "UpdateSlider('" + BCOMSPackageValidationList(0).PhaseInStatusReport.ToString() + "')", True)
```

but it's throwing the above error.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: `$("#slider-vertical").slider("values", PhaseInStatusReportVal);` ?

Comment: I tried it's throwing                                         Error: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'values'

Comment: did you find the root-cause ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you considered a different approach. Setup a hidden field with the initial value -> populate the value from the code-behind, then do something like:

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider-vertical").slider({
        value: $("#hiddenFieldWhatever").val(),
        // setup the rest ...
    });  
});
```

I hope I understood your requirements correct.

Comment: I have hard-coded the value, but it still throws the same error.

Answer (score 6):

```
var slider = $("#slider-vertical");

var a = function() {
    if(slider.slider("instance")) {
        slider.slider('value', 1);
        console.log('set value');
    } else {
        console.log('ERROR: cannot set value prior to initialization');
    }
}

var b = function() {
    slider.slider();
    console.log('initialized');
}

a();
b();
a();
```

Comment: Yep, this is the only option that worked for me to check if slider has been initialized on element: $(element).slider("instance")

Answer (score 1):

No answers explain the issue. The problem is that you're trying to create an event listener on a DOM element before the document is loaded:

If your chunk of code is supposed to run as soon as the page is loaded you can wrap it in a function to run as soon as the document loads:

```
document.onload=function(){
// Your Code Here
}
```

If the chunk of code runs dynamically inside a function you can simply wrap your code inside a check to make sure the document is loaded:

```
if (document. readyState === 'complete') {
//Your Code Here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the value of the slider you need to use the [value method](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-value)

```
$("#slider-vertical").slider("value", PhaseInStatusReportVal);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f4ar7/)

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you use the event from the ON function from the slider library you can get that value. Ex:

```
slider.on('slideStop', function(ev) {
    let value= ev.value; //try ev if you want to see all
    console.log(value);
})
```

Regards

Answer (score -1):

So I have seen this type of thing a lot.  You can do one of the following (AFAIK):

```
var slider;

$(function () { 
    var slider = $("#slider-vertical").slider({ 
        orientation: "horizantal",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 60, 
        slide: function (event, ui) { 
            $("#amount").val(ui.value); 
        } 
    }); 

    $("#amount").val(slider.slider("value")); 
});

function UpdateSlider(PhaseInStatusReportVal) {
    slider.slider("value").val(PhaseInStatusReportVal);
}
```

or

```
$("#slider-vertical").slider().slider("value").val(PhaseInStatusReportVal);
```

I like the first option better.

Comment: Are you getting the same exception with both options?

Comment: `.slider("value")` returns the value, not a jQuery object. You can't invoke `.val()` on that